# Telerik : Get Column name from FilterTemplate controls Client Event

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am trying to add RadCombobox to a telerik:GridTemplateColumn as a FilterTemplate control. I have multiple columns and all have RadCombobox with same filter values.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" HeaderStyle-Width="90px"
                            UniqueName="Date1" HeaderText="Date1" DataField="Day1">
                            <FilterTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxDate1" Height="90px" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                    Width="105px" runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="Date1IndexChanged">
                                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        function Date1IndexChanged(sender, args) {
                                            var tableView = $find("<%# TryCast(Container,GridItem).OwnerTableView.ClientID %>");
                                            var selectedValue = sender.get_value();
                                            if (selectedValue) {
                                                if (parseInt(selectedValue) < 0) {
      tableView.filter("Date1", selectedValue, "NoFilter");
                                                }
                                                else {                                                 tableView.filter("Date1", selectedValue, "EqualTo");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </script>
                                </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
                            </FilterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblday1"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdDay1" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Day1") %>' Visible="false" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

I have 7 such columns and I want to use a single RadCodeBlock to handle the filter. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given on Telerik website worked for me

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-get-column-name-from-filter-template-control-s-js-event